# heat map for adjusted and unadjusted correlation in the same plot

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation

For the variable set, I want to plot the unadjusted correlation and adjusted correlation for them in the same heat map plot. For example, I want to put the adjusted correlation in the lower triangle, and the unadjusted correlation in the upper triangle. Is there any reference code for this?

Comment: see the `corrplot` package

Comment: I see that this package can handle a lot of correlation heat maps, but no examples for my particular goal (lower and upper triangle for different correlations). Could you pls be more specific?

Comment: the [corrplot vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) has examples of lower and upper triangles. Also `?corrplot::corrplot` shows examples of creating upper and lower separately, and `add`ing them together.

Comment: Questioners on SO should post data-contruction using code and the code they have attempted at a solution.